# Semantics of APL dot operator?

Tags: apl

The dot `.` can be used to realize different types of products. For example,

```
1 2 3 +.× 4 5 6
```

I assumed the semantics of `a f.g b` was: compute `g(a[i], b[i])` then reduce using `f`. That is,

```
dot f g = f/a g¨ b ⍝ map g between a and b, and then reduce using f
```

To verify this, I wrote:

```
    ]display  a ← ⍳ 4 ⋄ b ← 4 +⍳ 4 ⋄  I ← { ((⊂ ⍺), (⊂ ⍵))} ⋄ a I.I b
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌→────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──────────────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │1 5│ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→────────────┐ │ │ │
│ │ └~──┘ │ │2 6│ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │ │ │ │
│ │       │ └~──┘ │ │3 7│ │4 8│ │ │ │ │
│ │       │       │ └~──┘ └~──┘ │ │ │ │
│ │       │       └∊────────────┘ │ │ │
│ │       └∊──────────────────────┘ │ │
│ └∊────────────────────────────────┘ │
└∊────────────────────────────────────┘
```

We can clearly see the right-fold of the elements, as it first maps the `I` creating
`(1 5) (2 6) (3 7) (4 8)` and then folds using `I` creating the nested structure,
so my definition seems to work!

---

However, this does not work for matrices:

```
      ]display a ← 2 2 ⍴ ⍳ 4 ⋄ b ← 4 + 2 2 ⍴ ⍳ 4 ⋄   I ← { ((⊂ ⍺), (⊂ ⍵))} ⋄ a I.I b
┌→────────────────────────────────┐
↓ ┌→────────────┐ ┌→────────────┐ │
│ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │ │
│ │ │1 5│ │2 7│ │ │ │1 6│ │2 8│ │ │
│ │ └~──┘ └~──┘ │ │ └~──┘ └~──┘ │ │
│ └∊────────────┘ └∊────────────┘ │
│ ┌→────────────┐ ┌→────────────┐ │
│ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │ │
│ │ │3 5│ │4 7│ │ │ │3 6│ │4 8│ │ │
│ │ └~──┘ └~──┘ │ │ └~──┘ └~──┘ │ │
│ └∊────────────┘ └∊────────────┘ │
└∊────────────────────────────────┘
```

Interesting! so it seems to actually compute some sort of outer product between its elements in this case, and not a "fold"?  My hypothetical definition of the `.` operator does not perform
the same operation:

```
]display a ← 2 2 ⍴ ⍳ 4 ⋄ b ← 4 + 2 2 ⍴ ⍳ 4 ⋄   I ← { ((⊂ ⍺), (⊂ ⍵))} ⋄ I/a I¨b
┌→────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌→────────────┐ ┌→────────────┐ │
│ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │ │ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │ │
│ │ │1 5│ │2 6│ │ │ │3 7│ │4 8│ │ │
│ │ └~──┘ └~──┘ │ │ └~──┘ └~──┘ │ │
│ └∊────────────┘ └∊────────────┘ │
└∊────────────────────────────────┘
```

So, **what are the actual semantics of `.`(dot) in APL**? How would I discover this by myself?

Comment: `f.g` ←→ `f⌿a g¨ b` - note that `f⌿` reduces by first axis; `f/` reduces by last axis

Comment: also: `((⊂ ⍺), (⊂ ⍵))` ←→ `⍺⍵`, known as "stranding"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dyalog help page on "Inner Product"](http://help.dyalog.com/17.1/#Language/Primitive%20Operators/Inner%20Product.htm):

> ## `R←X f.g Y`
>
> The result of the derived function has shape `(¯1↓⍴X),1↓⍴Y`; each item is `f/x g¨y` where `x` and `y` are vectors taken from all the combinations of vectors along the last axis of `X` and the first axis of `Y`.

In the case of `vector f.g vector`, it is fine to understand it as `f/ vector g¨ vector` as you already observed. However, it gets more complicated for matrices and higher-dimensional arrays.

For matrices, the most straightforward usage (and the most cited one) is the "matrix product" `+.×`. Mathematically, for an m-by-n matrix X and n-by-p matrix Y, `X +.× Y` is defined as an m-by-p matrix whose element at `[i;j]` is the vector dot product (sum of element-wise products) of `i`th row of X and `j`th column of Y. For an illustration, refer to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

In this case, the array X (an m-by-n matrix) has shape (`⍴`) of `m n`, and Y has shape `n p`. The result has shape `m p`, which is equal to `(¯1↓m n),1↓n p`.

If we generalize this definition to arbitrary functions `f` and `g`, (for matrices X and Y) we can define `X f.g Y` to be another matrix whose elements are "reduction by f" of "element-wise g"s of each row of X and each column of Y. This is precisely what the doc is talking about when it mentions `f/x g¨ y`. Also, X has m rows and Y has p columns, so calculating *all combinations* of each row of X and each column of Y will give precisely `m×p` values.

So far, we've covered more than half of the doc's sentence. Then what does "vectors along the last axis of `X`" mean? For the matrix X of shape `m n`, the last axis has length `n`, so the matrix X can be viewed as `m` vectors of length `n`. Similarly, "vectors along the *first* axis of `Y`" means viewing the shape `n p` matrix Y as `p` vectors of length `n`. Then the two length-`n` vectors (one from X and the other from Y) become the arguments of `g¨`, which implies that the lengths must match.

We can also generalize this concept to higher-dimensional arrays. If we have an `a×b×c` array X, it has `a×b` vectors of length `c` (last axis). If we have another `c×d×e` array Y, it has `d×e` vectors of length `c` (first axis). Then computing over all combinations of vectors will give `a×b×d×e` elements, which naturally gives the result array of shape `a b d e`.

Summarizing all of this, `X f.g Y` is equivalent to extracting last-axis vectors of X and first-axis vectors of Y and computing the *outer product* of `f/ x g¨ y` over the vectors:

```
a ← 2 3 3⍴⍳4
b ← 3 3 4⍴⍳5
f ← {⍺+⊂⍵}
g ← {⍺⍵}
⎕←(a f.g b) ≡ (↓[≢⍴a]a) ∘.{⊃ f/ ⍺ g¨ ⍵} (↓[1]b)
```

This program prints 1, i.e. true. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P1HhUdsEBSMFYwXjR71bHvVuNuFKAgsBBRRMIEKmXGlgoepHvbu0H3U1PerdWsuVDhcCcx/1TQXyNRIV0vTSFZI0FR51LlTQeNQ2OfpR5yKgKYmxiUCxjhl61Y@6mhXS9BWA@hTSD61QAGmGKDSMTdL8/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of inner product (`f.g`) actually varies slightly between dialects. In the following, I'll disregard singleton arguments, as they are treated as scalars.

#### Dyalog's definition

[Dyalog's documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Operators/Inner%20Product.htm) leads to the model `{⍺(⍺⍺⌿⍵⍵¨⍤¯1)⍤1 999⊢⍵}`. [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u237A%u2375%7D%7B%u237A%28%u237A%u237A%u233F%u2375%u2375%A8%u2364%AF1%29%u23641%20999%u22A2%u2375%7D%7B%u237A%u2375%7D%u23682%202%u2374%u23734&run)

#### IBM's definition

[IBM's documentation](https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/ZOKMYKOY#page=181) leads to the Dyalog APL (!) model `{⍺⍺/¨(⊂⍤1⊢⍺)∘.⍵⍵⍉⊂⍤1⍉⍵}`. [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u237A%u2375%7D%7B%u237A%u237A/%A8%28%u2282%u23641%u22A2%u237A%29%u2218.%u2375%u2375%u2349%u2282%u23641%u2349%u2375%7D%7B%u237A%u2375%7D%u23682%202%u2374%u23734&run)